# CSS selector in dotnetcore?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, .net-core

I was using `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;` in .NET to get elements using CSS selectors. Now I'm porting my project over to .NET core and there doesn't seem to be a 
Fizzler although HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore is available. How do I use CSS selectors?

Comment: you were using Fizzler in .NET and now you are porting your project over to... .NET ?

Comment: @Veverke: I forgot the core somewhere in there but yes I am porting .NET to .NET

Comment: what about ScrapySharp or AngleSharp like I suggested below, do they do the job ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the [`HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors.NetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors.NetCore/) NuGet package reference to your project.

Here is an example of how to use the `QuerySelectorAll()` method.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

IList<HtmlNode> nodes = doc.QuerySelectorAll("div .my-class[data-attr=123] > ul li");
HtmlNode node = nodes[0].QuerySelector("p.with-this-class span[data-myattr]");
```

*Source: [github.com/trenoncourt](https://github.com/trenoncourt/HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors.NetCore)*

Answer (score 0):

I used HtmlAgilitypack like below:

```
string url = "your URL";

                HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                web.PreRequest = delegate (HttpWebRequest webRequest)
                {
                    webRequest.Timeout = 15000;
                    return true;
                };
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

List<HtmlNode> findclasses = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d =>
        d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("YourClassName")
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

For CSS selectors in .NET, I always used [ScrapySharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ScrapySharp) (although it does not support pseudo-elements).

Add `ScrapySharp.Extensions` to your using statements, and all you need is to invoke `CssSelect` in any HtmlNode object, such as `DocumentNode`.

```
using ScrapySharp.Extensions;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ConsoleLab
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            var document = web.Load("your url");
            //css class selector example
            var res1 = document.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".yourClass");
            //css id selector example
            var res2 = document.DocumentNode.CssSelect("#yourID");
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative solution is to use [AngleSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngleSharp) - which is an all-in-one package for parsing and css-selecting (css selectors are built in). It's been a while since I use these, but if I am not wrong angle sharp offers better css selector support.

`Anglesharp` usage examples:

```
    //parsing a http-served url (asynchronous, used .Result here for simplification, but this defeats the asynchronoability of the code)
    IBrowsingContext bc = BrowsingContext.New();
    Task<IDocument> doc = bc.OpenAsync("yourAddress");
    //querying a single selector match
    IElement element1 = doc.Result.QuerySelector(".yourSelector");
    //querying multiple selector matches
    IEnumerable<IElement> elements1 = doc.Result.QuerySelectorAll(".yourSelectors");

    //parsing a physical html document, non-network dependent
    HtmlParser parser = new HtmlParser();
    IHtmlDocument doc2 = parser.Parse("htmlFile");
    IElement element2 = doc.Result.QuerySelector(".yourSelector");
    IEnumerable<IElement> elements2 = doc.Result.QuerySelectorAll(".yourSelectors");
```